# Ruby on Rails + Devise + I18n: how to set locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, devise

I use before_filter in ApplicationController to set locale for my application:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  before_filter :set_locale

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = request.compatible_language_from ["uk", "ru", "de", "en"]
  end
end
```

It works for controllers that are written by me. But all devise's messages are still English.

Setting `config.i18n.default_locale = "uk"` (or other) in `config/application.rb` works, so I guess that the trouble is that devise's controller does not use my before_filter (possibly, it does not inherit `ApplicationController` at all (?)).

How to resolve this problem? How to make devise use my locale?

Comment: devise uses your apps ApplicationController. this is configurable through the parent_controller setting.

Comment: @Hauleth Yes, I did. And they work if I set non-English locale as default with config.i18n.default_locale in application.rb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Devise Wiki https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n
They have lots of YML file samples.

If you still wanna write your own, try using something like this in your I18n files

```
en:
  devise:
    sessions:
      signed_in: 'Signed in successfully.'
```

More info on GitHub https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#i18n

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prepend_before_action` (or `prepend_before_filter` but it is alias of `prepend_before_action` and is soon going to be deprecated) so you should have something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  prepend_before_action :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = request.compatible_language_from [:uk, :ru, :de, :en]
  end
end
```

**Note** that this may break the `I18n.locale` in your views so you may need to set it in additional `before_action`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where my french devise locales were loading for everyone, and the problem was that my devise locales were originally built in their own file - `devise.en.yml`. I moved them into the `en.yml` file, and everything was fixed.

Hopefully this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default locale in `config/application.rb` or `config/initializers/locale.rb` by:

```
# Set default locale to something other than :en
I18n.default_locale = :fa
```

as suggested by the [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module)

Then, you should add related `yml` translation files like: `fa.yml`. The files should be located in `locales` dir where default `en` files are exist. You can also set a custom directory to be loaded.